# i3wm manjaro gnome applications appear to head dbus timeout

Tags: manjaro, i3

In my manjaro installation, since the latest update, gnome applications such as the gnome calculator and gedit, aswell as firefox, blueman-manager and pamac-manager take about 25 seconds to startup. It seems they are hitting the dbus timeout. Certain applications such as chromium, urxvt and pcmanfm appear unaffected. I tried stracing it, and it gets stuck at the following line, although its inconclusive:

```
20:56:42 close(10)                      = 0
20:56:42 write(6, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
20:56:42 write(6, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
20:56:42 futex(0x55d65cddfa48, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
20:56:42 eventfd2(0, EFD_CLOEXEC|EFD_NONBLOCK) = 10
20:56:42 poll([{fd=10, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
20:56:43 --- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
20:56:43 restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted poll ...>
```

Is there aby way I can diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of the `xdg-desktop-portal` and `xdg-desktop-portal-gtk` packages fixed it.